# In Java, what is the advantage of using BufferedWriter to append to a file?

Tags: java

I'm looking at the following [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/WriteToFile.html)

Which uses the following code

```
try {
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename"));
      out.write("aString");
      out.close();
    } 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

What's the advantage over doing

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfilename");
```

I have tried both and they seem comparable in speed when it comes to the task of appending to a file one line at a time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) provides a reasonable discussion on this subject:

> In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying
>   character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is
>   advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write()
>   operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.
>   For example,
>
> ```
>  PrintWriter out    = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new 
>      FileWriter("foo.out")));
> ```
>
> will buffer the PrintWriter's output to the
>   file. Without buffering, each invocation of a print() method would
>   cause characters to be converted into bytes that would then be written
>   immediately to the file, which can be very inefficient.

If you're writing large blocks of text at once (like entire lines) then you probably won't notice a difference.  If you have a lot of code that appends a single character at a time, however, a `BufferedWriter` will be much more efficient.

**Edit**

As per andrew's comment below, the `FileWriter` actually uses its own fixed-size 1024 byte buffer.  This was confirmed by looking at the [source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/OutputStreamWriter-source.html).  The `BufferedWriter` [sources](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/BufferedWriter-source.html), on the other hand, show that it uses and 8192 byte buffer size (default), which can be configured by the user to any other desired size.  So it seems like the benefits of `BufferedWriter` vs. `FileWriter` are limited to:

- Larger default buffer size.
- Ability to override/customize the buffer size.

And to further muddy the waters, the [Java 6 implementation](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.java.html) of `OutputStreamWriter` actually delegates to a [StreamEncoder](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/nio/cs/StreamEncoder.java.html), which uses its own buffer with a default size of 8192 bytes.  And the `StreamEncoder` buffer is user-configurable, although there is no way to access it directly through the enclosing `OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: i think this is wrong.  as it says in the javadocs, the filewriter does have a buffer - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: @andrew - Good point, my answer was based upon what the `BufferedWriter` Javadoc stated.  However, after looking at some of the [source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/OutputStreamWriter-source.html) it appears you are correct, at least for `FileWriter`.  Anything derived from `OutputStreamWriter` will use a fixed-size 1024 byte buffer.

Comment: yeah, it's surprising.  i was going to write an answer similar to yours til i stumbled across the comment in outputsteamwriter.

Comment: That was probably just added because many, many people ignored the best practice and didn't buffer their filewriter :/ But then calling the multibyte conversion on larger strings is much more efficient than otherwise (that's at least true on windows, but I assume the same goes for linux as well)

Comment: @Voo actually, that “best practice” of mindlessly wrapping every stream into a buffered counterpart, is what should be questioned. I’ve seen buffered streams being wrapped in another buffered stream, due to code first wrapping any arbitrary received stream. Whereas most streams are intrinsically buffered already and when not, using a buffered stream only helps when you make a lot of too small read or write requests, so that’s what should be fixed (consequently, NIO channels do not have such buffered wrappers). And well, the OP’s example is such an example not benefiting from buffering at all.

Answer (score 5):

this is explained in the javadocs for outputstreamwriter.  a filewriter *does* have a buffer (in the underlying outputstreamwriter), but the character encoding converter is invoked on each call to write.  using an outer buffer avoids calling the converter so often.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Comment: …and the performance of the charset encoder really depends on how often you call it (rather than the total amount of characters)?

Answer (score 2):

A buffer effectivity is more easily seen when the load is high. Loop the out.write a couple thousand of times and you should see a difference.

For a few bytes passed in just one call probably the BufferedWriter is even worse (because it problably later calls FileOutputStream).