# What is the default size of the buffer used by FileWriter?

Tags: java, size, buffer

What is the default size of buffer used by `FileWriter` ? Till I close the file as :

```
writer.close()
```

the buffer doesn't get flushed. So,what is the limit of my doing :

```
writer.write(string)
```

Comment: note, you can use `writer.flush()` to flush the data to the file without closing the writer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976933/2231632

The file writer uses a default buffer size of 1024 bytes. That thread also provided enough discussion for starters as to what are the limitations of a FileWriter.

Comment: actually, FileWriter _is_ buffered.  there is a buffer in the utility which converts the chars to bytes.

Comment: silly me. I said default buffer size in the first line and still typed that it is not buffered. I wanted to say it is buffered. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: What will happen if keep on putting the data in the buffer ? Will it automatically flush or will overflow ? I guess it automatically flushes